# Adding more arrays to an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to add more arrays to an array.

```
$data[$username] = array('bytes' => $bytes, 'ip' => array( $ip => array('bytes' => $bytes)));
```

How do you add one more array to `ip` array?

I tried this but wont work.

```
 $data[$username]['ip'] = array($ip => array('bytes' => $bytes));
```

Comment: `$data[$username]['ip'][] = array($ip => array('bytes' => $bytes));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have your data array...

```
$data[$username] = array(
    'bytes' => $bytes, // bytes?
    'ip' => array(
        $ip => array(
            'bytes' => $bytes // bytes again?
        }
    )
);
```

To add more key/value pairs to the ip array, you need to do the following, assuming $ip is not already a key in the array. If it is, it will overwrite the value currently at that key.

```
$data[$username]['ip'][$ip] = array(
    'bytes' => $bytes
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$data[$username]['ip'][$ip] = array('bytes' => $bytes);
```

This will add another `array('bytes' => $bytes)` to the `$data[$username]['ip']` array.